# How can I convert a folder with a lot of .bin files to their respective .iso on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: iso, convert, binary

I have a folder with +100 .bin (and only .bin) files which I want to convert to their respective .iso (a.bin -> a.iso, b.bin -> b.iso), and so on. I only found on the net examples on how to convert a single file, one at a time, but that I already know how to do. How do I convert a whole folder at once? I saw examples using iat and bchunk, but as far as I could tell, I couldn't use them for a whole folder, as in, say, tochd when converting to .chd.

Comment: provide the command you use by editing it in the question. The solution is to make a 'loop' around the command where the filename in your current command is changed to 
 a variable.  Was it `bchunck` perhaps?

Comment: How do I create a loop using the commands in my edited question?